# Require stronger password for some users based on roles

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, security, asp.net-membership, authorization

I have a MVC 3 app. There are mainly two zones regarding security. The first one is mostly to prevent public access, but not really sensitive information. Password strength might be weak since there is not really much harm to do either.

Second zone(Area) is restricted. user must apply for access. If user gets access it gets a certain role(s). So each controller method autorizes the user based on that role.

I want these users to have to change password to a strong password on the next logon before they can go further and access the restricted content.

**Example:**

> User A applies for access. 
>   Access is granted. The password policy for
>   that user is changed as long as it has access. They MUST
>   change their password on the next logon, and they cannot change back
>   to a weaker password as long as they have that role.

Is there any secure way to implement this using the ASP.NET?

**Update**

I've actually used Chris proposed solution and it works, but to handle the verification of the password itself I actually got some inspiration from Micah's proposed solution too. However, it turns out that overriding MembershipProvider.OnValidatingPassword does imply also having to implement 10 + abstract methods that I really do not need to solve this.

A better solution in my eyes was hooking on to the Membership.ValidatingPassword EVENT. I do this inn App_Start, then I implement my own password validation in the event handler and that solved my problem.

Just to share the solution with you i present it here, toghether with Chris solution this solved my problem and hopefully for someone else too:

```
    void App_Start()
    {
        //To do custom validation on certain passwords set new event handler
        Membership.ValidatingPassword += Membership_ValidatingPassword;
    }

private void Membership_ValidatingPassword(object sender, ValidatePasswordEventArgs e)
    {
        //If the user is a new user, we let registration happen without strong password
        if (e.IsNewUser) return;


        MembershipUser membershipUser = Membership.GetUser(e.UserName);
        Guid userId = Guid.Parse(membershipUser.ProviderUserKey.ToString());

        //First check if the pwd is strong enough to be flagged, if so we flag it
        //using regex to validate the password (20 char, 2 uppercase so on)
        if (MyValidationClass.IsStrongPassword(e.Password, 20, 2, 4, 1))
        {
            //if the user does not already have a flag we set one
            MyValidationClass.SetStrongPasswordFlag(userId);
        }
        else
        {
            //If the user needs strong pwd, we cancel the operation and throw exception
            if (MyValidationClass.NeedsStrongPassword(e.UserName))
            {
                e.FailureInformation =
                    new MembershipPasswordException("Password does not satisfy reqirements!");
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
            else
            {
                MyValidationClass.RemoveStrongPasswordFlag(userId);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: have you ever read or search anything regarding [Membership and Roles](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-secure-my-site-using-membership-and-roles) in .NET?

Comment: how can request a strong password before the roles set on ? Now on change password you can do that programmaticaly, but not before.

Comment: @belexandre Yes, I've read quite a bit about it, but I haven't seen information about this. I've done searches on the question above, but not found information on other than role-based authentication. That is not my question, the question is that you might have really strong password requirements for the things you regard as confidential, but normal strong or even weak for other content. I've not seen all videos though. You mean there is information about this in the video link above?

Comment: @Aristos If I understand you right: When you apply, an admin user sets the role on your user. Then you get that role. next time you get authorized (either by logging in or by trying to access restriced content) you shoud be redirected to upgrade your password.

Comment: all this steps that you describe here must be done pro grammatically by you. They not exist all ready.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write your own Authorize Attribute to accommodate both. You simply need to then use it on the relevant sections of your application:

For example:

```
public class HasChangedPasswordAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{      
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        UserRepository repo = new UserRepository();
        var user = repo.GetCurrentUser();
        bool hasSecurelyChangedPassword = user.HasSecurelyChangedPassword;
        return hasSecurelyChangedPassword;
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/Account/ChangePassword");
    }
}
```

The above will check that the user has securely changed their password. If not it will redirect them to a new page in which to change their password. Once they change it, set the flag as changed.

You can then use it like this:

```
[HasChangedPassword]
[Authorize(Roles="SuperRole")]
public ActionResult MySecureAction()
{
 ...
}
```

You could obviously integrate both of these attributes into one, but for the sake of showing the example they are seperated above.

Comment: Hmm, this got me on to something. I already have a global filter for the whole site for basic authorization. If I add the logic to check the user roles and i it is in a spesific role certain rules apply - the same as above. Is there any functionality in ASP.NET membership to check the password strength. It is not stored in plain text so it is not as easy to actually get the users password.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to get it once its set, but if you force the user to change their password (like above) you could check at the point they submit it. And then store a flag in the DB if the user has it securely set.

Comment: Thanks, that is probably a viable way to do it. Trying to think of the security implications. The only I can think of is that storing the flag unencrypted in the database might be a concern... On the other hand, noone can change that flag... I'll have to work a bit on this, thanks.

Comment: I've worked out a solution for this now, and it works just as planned in my tests. So thanks, this headed me in the right direction. However, would you think there is a big performance impact to hit the database on every request as the user table grows?

Answer (score 1):

you will need override the MembershipProvider.OnValidatingPassword

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.onvalidatingpassword.aspx

Comment: Do you need the source code to make a new provider or is it sufficient to override the OnValidatePassword?

Comment: You should be able to inherit from MembershipProvider and override the OnValidatingPassword. I was thinking you would have to use the one given. Looking at it more that might not be the case

Comment: I'll have to look into this, but for future maintenance overriding a method is probably better than building a custom provider...

Answer (score -1):

Probably a simpler method would be check the strength of the password on the client-side when you user is attempting to enter a new password.  Check out this [list](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/10-password-strength-meter-scripts-for-a-better-registration-interface/) for some examples using JQuery.

In regard the transaction of upgrading and resetting the password, that's something your code can handle, i.e. a flag in the users table that redirects the user to a new registration page.  But when they set the password (and presumably it matches the appropriate strength) it can then be submitted...

Comment: Password complexity should be validated server side for security reasons

Comment: Using jQuery is easily bypassed i think. It must be done on server side somehow, and jQuery as a help to see if it meets the requirements.